# Brightness native plugin shows -1.0

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-native

Can you tell me why [**brightness**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/brightness/) native plugin shows `-1.0` as the first time?

When I changed it and get again it shows correctly.But first time having above issue.Because my device default brightness is `80%`.It should show that as `0.8` by default no?

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.brightness.getBrightness().then((res: number) => {
          this.settings.brightness = Math.abs(res * 100);
          console.log('init:', res);
          }).catch((err) => {
          console.error(err)
        })
      });
  }
```

**output**

```
init: -1.0
```

Comment: According to [the plugin docs](https://github.com/mgcrea/cordova-plugin-brightness): _// success([-1,0-1]) float 0-1 is a brightness level, -1 represents a system default_. So the `-1` seems to be because it's the _system default_...

Comment: By default Android device should have a value greater than `0` no? Why it shows `-1` then?@sebaferreras

Comment: All I can find is that `It returns -1 in case of system default brightness.`. Have you tried to set it and then get the value again, to see if it changes?

Comment: Yes.When I changed it and get again it shows correctly.But first time having above issue.Because my device default brightness is `80%`.It should show that 0.8 by default no? @sebaferreras

Comment: The docs doesn't say much about that value, but maybe the -1 means that _it was not set manually yet_... but I was not able to find anything else about that -1... just that is a **valid result considered by the plugin** (I mean, it's not an exception nor an error code)

Comment: Hmm..It seems an issue of plugin no? The issue is, it doesn't pick the device's default value no (e.g. `0.8`)? @sebaferreras